# Error installing Xdebug via pecl on Mac - Unable to create temp directory

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, xdebug, pecl

On Mac Monterey, while trying to install `xdebug` via `pecl` as is now required with Homebrew, I get the following error:

```
downloading xdebug-3.2.0.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-3.2.0.tgz (245,775 bytes)
....................................................done: 245,775 bytes

Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in System.php on line 420
PHP Notice:  tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.13/share/php/pear/System.php on line 420

Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.13/share/php/pear/System.php on line 420

Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in System.php on line 420
PHP Notice:  tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.13/share/php/pear/System.php on line 420

Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.13/share/php/pear/System.php on line 420
ERROR: failed to mkdir /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/m4
```

I have tried changing perms with `chmod` in `/private/tmp` but that makes no difference. I have verified that XCode command line tools are installed and up to date, and I have completely uninstalled - including manually removing directories after uninstall - and re-installing PHP (currently at v8.1.13) via Homebrew, but I still can't get past this error.

What do I need to do to get Xdebug installed via pecl?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set your temporary path to something that you know has full write access by setting the `temp_dir` configuration setting in PECL:

```
pecl config-set temp_dir /home/<youruser>/tmp`
```

And then make sure that directory exists.